# Error with function returning string

Tags: python, syntax-error

I need help with a cryptic error message with python:

```
def format1(arg1,arg2,arg3,bf):
    yu = 0
    if(bf):
        yu = concat(concat("Back: [",numtostr(arg1)),concat("]: ",concat(arg2,concat(" -- ",arg3))))
    else:
        yu = concat(concat("Forward: [",numtostr(arg1),concat("]: ",concat(arg2,concat(" -- ",arg3))))
    return yu
```

result:

```
  File "testdirectoryscroll2.py", line 27
    return yu
         ^
```

??? :D

Comment: That error message is only "cryptic" because you didn't post the entire thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a missing closing parenthesis in the previous line:

```
yu = concat(concat("Forward: [",numtostr(arg1)),concat("]: ",concat(arg2,concat(" -- ",arg3))))
                                              ^
```

Comment: Possibly it's missing after `numtostr(arg1)` instead (as in the first case). Might be relevant depending on what `concat` does.

Comment: Concat just concatenates 2 strings